# Could there be a M-type asteroid beyond Jupiter?

Tags: asteroids, orbital-migration, centaur

Is there any reason to think an M-type asteroid could not have migrated beyond Jupiter and entered an orbit similar to the Centaurs?

Comment: Then it would *be* a centaur, would it not? How would we still know it was an M-type asteroid?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I was under the impression centaurs are icy, comet-like bodies, who were originally KBO, astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/C/Centaurs. I thought the metallic asteroids originated in the Asteroid Belt. I'm not asking if such an asteroid could be identified, just is there any reason a metallic asteroid could not end up in an orbit between Jupiter and Neptune.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Grand Tack Hypothesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_tack_hypothesis), in the early solar system, Jupiter and Saturn migrated inwards and then outwards, scattering asteroids as they did so.

In this hypothesis it seems inevitable that *some* m-type asteroids will have ended up in orbits with large semi-major axes.